# Concurrency Problem in spring boot: "out of memory" on 16GB ram allocation but only consuming 6GB

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

> "http-nio-8080-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Getting above error when calling my rest apis (using elasticsearch as dataabse) when using apache ab with command

> ab -n 20 -n 1000 "localhost:8080/getData"

running jar using below command

> nohup java -Xms 2g -Xmx 16g server.jar

Even with these settings java is using 6 - 8GB ram and not more than that but ends up giving OOM issue or sometimes just dies without any error on load testing.

how do I resolve this ? As launching multiple instances under a load balancer will not solve this problem

Below is the error stack:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.<init>(Http11OutputBuffer.java:126)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:238)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.createProcessor(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:636)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:771)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.<init>(Http11OutputBuffer.java:126)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:238)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.createProcessor(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:636)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:771)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-2" Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.init(Http11InputBuffer.java:717)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:980)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-7" Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-15" Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-16" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-12" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-14" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-13" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-18" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-19" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-29" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Currently using java 8

Comment: OK ... so according to https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/11/02/how-choose-best-java-garbage-collector, you should probably be using the G1 collector.  Add the `-XX:+UseG1GC` option.  This will give better performance, especially with larger heaps.  ZGC would also be an option, though you should be running Java 17 or later to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but threads were waiting for something. Tomcat spawns new threads for handling new requests and the GC was not clearing the object the thread was using from heap.

Even though elasticsearch response response comes within 5ms I'm assuming maybe this was due to elasticsearch response time in certain cases and for those threads it returns memory overflow.

However this doesn't explain the why it was not using all the available ram.

My hacked solution:

set the min thread count of tomcat to 1 and max to 10. tomcat will not spawn new threads and no heap over utilization.

If someone had encountered this kind of problem maybe the can provide better insights